# How do I string concat two columns in Scala but order the resulting column alphabetically?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this...

```
  val new_df =Seq(("a","b"),("b","a"),("a","c")).toDF("col1","col2")
```

and I want to create "`col3`" which is a string concatenation of "`col1`" and "`col2`". However, I want the concatenation of "ab" and "ba" to be treated the same, sorted alphabetically so that it's only "ab".

The resulting dataframe I would like to look like this:

```
  val new_df =Seq(("a","b","ab"),("b","a","ab"),("a","c","ac")).toDF("col1","col2","col3")
```

And here's a before and after picture too:

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

thanks and have a great day!

Comment: What have you tried and what are you stuck with?

Answer (score 2):

With Spark SQL functions to take advantage of the Spark SQL Optimizations:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sort_array, array, concat_ws}

new_df.withColumn("col3", 
  concat_ws("", 
    sort_array(array(col("col1"), col("col2")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an `udf` to create a sorted String

```
  val concatColumns = udf((c1: String, c2: String) => {
    List(c1, c2).sorted.mkString
  })
```

And then use it in a `withColumn` statement sending the desired columns to concatenate

```
 new_df.withColumn("col3", concatColumns($"col1", $"col2")).show(false)
```

**Result**

```
  +----+----+----+
    |col1|col2|col3|
    +----+----+----+
    |a   |b   |ab  |
    |b   |a   |ab  |
    |a   |c   |ac  |
    +----+----+----+
```